# How to combine a video and an image using "reverse" vstack?

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg

I have an image and a video (same width). I now want to use ffmpeg to add the image above the video. Google and other SO threads the use of the vstack filter_complex tag, which works great - except that it puts the image under the video.

I've tried putting the image first and then the video, but this doesnt work. I've also tried giving the vstack command reverse inputs, but also didnt work!

The video *may* also contain audio which I would need to keep.

See code below:

```
// Works, but puts image below video (instead of above)
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i text.png -filter_complex vstack result.mp4

// Doesn't work at all
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i text.png -filter_complex '[1:v][0:v]vstack' result.mp4

// Doesn't work at all
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i text.png -filter_complex '[1:v][0:v]vstack=inputs=2[v]' -map '[v]' -map 0:a result.mp4
```

Google / SO did not yield any tips on how to achieve this so far. Do you know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i text.png -filter_complex '[1:v][0:v]vstack' -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p result.mp4
```

Videos and images can have different pixel formats. When the various inputs to a stack filter don't have the same format, the filter picks the format of the first input and converts all other inputs to that format. However, some video players don't support a wide variety of formats. `yuv420p` is the widely supported format and so the command above forces the output to that one. Audio, if present in the MP4, will get carried over.

---

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i text.png -filter_complex '[1:v]format=yuv444p[img];[img][0:v]vstack' -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p result.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried your code and unfortunately it looks it causes the video to lose color: input https://imgur.com/XGiReuT --> output https://imgur.com/es7sJdP Other than that it's exactly what I need!